# Refresh required to detect authentication state using nuxt auth module

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

My app is unable to detect the state change that occurs when a user logs in without completely refreshing the page. Upon refreshing everything displays correctly. I am using Nuxt and its included auth module documented here - https://auth.nuxtjs.org/.

Here is the v-if statement that is unable to detect the state change:

```
  <template v-if="$auth.$state.loggedIn">
    <nuxt-link
      to="/profile"
    >
      Hello, {{ $auth.$state.user.name }}
    </nuxt-link>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    <nuxt-link
      to="/logIn"
    >
      Sign In
    </nuxt-link>
  </template>
```

Here is the login method in my login page.

```
  methods: {
    async onLogin() {
      try{

        this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
          data: {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
          }
        });

        this.$router.push("/");

      }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
      }

    }
  }
```

I tried fetching the state via a computed property but got the same result. I can see the vuex store data change to indicate I am correctly logged in/out in the 'Application' tab in Chrome Dev Tools but the Vue Dev seems to constantly indicate I'm logged in.. Not sure if its just buggy though..

I also encounter the same problem in reverse when logging out. Here's the method:

```
async onLogout() {
  try{
    await this.$auth.logout();
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

I am happy to provide further details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. In `store/index.js` add this :

   ```
    export const getters = {
      isAuthenticated(state) {
      return state.auth.loggedIn
     },
      loggedInUser(state) {
      return state.auth.user
     },
   };
   ```
2. In the pages you are suppose to be authenticated

   - use middle ware auth as : `middleware: 'auth'`
   - use `import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'`
   - in computed add `...mapGetters(['isAuthenticated', 'loggedInUser']),`
3. you can use  loggedInUser to get your user details or check if isAuthenticated

and the logout would work as expected as long as your are importing the map getters in the computed

Comment: This does not solve the problem that if you clear out the cookies and localstorage and click a few more pages in the app under SPA, it does not check authentication again, therefore logged out users are still accessing pages they should not.

Comment: Actually it does , if you are using middleware:auth and  the mapGetters  in some layout and uses this layout for all  auth pages  it checks if you're authenticated  for all these pages ubder this middleware when visited . there for when deleting the localstotage it redirect you back to login page but you should  define the auth stratigy in nuxt.config.js

Comment: I know I'm nearly 3 years late but isAuthenticated is still returning true when I'm logged out. I logged in, opened the app in two tabs and when I logged out of one the other doesn't get logged out and can process axios requests until I've refreshed the page.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes Vue's reactivity system falls short and you just need to manually trigger a re-render and the simplest way to do so is by wrapping your function logic in `setTimeout()`

```js
setTimeout(async () => {
   await this.$auth.logout();
}, 0);
```